JDBC ResultSet has more data than selected
I am selecting data from an AS/400 database from different tables using a change indicator. I then export the data to a file and mark the data as exported by updating this change indicator.
While this process is active it is possible that users enter new data and for some reason this new data is added to our ResultSet and gets marked as exported, too. What could cause this behaviour?
Here are excerpts of the code:
stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
extractedData = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

private void writeDataToFile(TableIdentifier table, String tableHeader, ResultSet extractedData,
        TableMetaData tableMetaData, Date currentTimestamp) {
    BufferedFileWriter bfw = null;
    boolean shouldUpdate = true;
    try {
        logger.info(Message.COLLECTOR_EXPORT_START, table.getName());
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = extractedData.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (ExportConfig config : tableQueueMap.get(table)) {
            expDir = WorkDir.getWorkDir(context, applicationDomain + File.separator + EXPDIR + File.separator
                    + (config.isSendComplete() ? "complete_" : "") + config.getSendQueue());
            String[] qualTable = table.getName().split("\\.");
            String tableName = table.getName();
            if (qualTable.length > 1) {
                tableName = qualTable[1];
            }
            File exportFile = new File(expDir, tableName);

            if (!exportFile.exists()) {
                bfw = new BufferedFileWriter(exportFile);
                writeHeader(tableHeader, bfw);
            } else {
                bfw = new BufferedFileWriter(exportFile, true);
            }
            writeLines(tableName, extractedData, bfw, numberOfColumns);
            setTimestamp(table.getName(), currentTimestamp, config);
            bfw.close();
            if (config.isSendComplete()) {
                shouldUpdate = false;
            }
        }
        if (tableMetaData.getUpdate() != null && shouldUpdate) {
            extractedData.beforeFirst();
            if (tableMetaData.getVersion() != null) {
                markDataAsExported(extractedData, tableMetaData);
            } else {
                markResultSetAsExported(extractedData, tableMetaData);
            }
        }
        tableQueueMap.remove(table);
        dataExported = true;
    } catch (IOException ex0) {
        logger.error(Message.COLLECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_ERROR, table.getName(), ex0.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException ex1) {
        logger.error(Message.COLLECTOR_RESULTSET_ERROR, table.getName(), ex1.getMessage());
    } catch (WorkDirException ex2) {
        logger.error(Message.COLLECTOR_WORKDIR_ERROR, ex2.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (bfw != null)
            try {
                bfw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore
            }
    }
}

private void markResultSetAsExported(ResultSet extractedData, TableMetaData tableMetaData) throws SQLException {
    while (extractedData.next()) {
        if (tableMetaData.getUpdateColumnType().equals("N")) {
            extractedData.updateInt(tableMetaData.getUpdateColumn(),
                    Integer.parseInt(tableMetaData.getUpdateValue()));
        } else {
            extractedData.updateString(tableMetaData.getUpdateColumn(), tableMetaData.getUpdateValue());
        }
        extractedData.updateRow();
    }
}

When I debug the code I can see that on extractedData.next() in the method markResultSetAsExported the result set has grown if new data has been added to the table.

What isolation level do you use on your transactions?

There is none configured. What would the default value be?

It's happening because you set your ResultSet to CONCUR_UPDATABLE. Change ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE to ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY.

Unfortunately I need to update the ResultSet.

@Moh-Aw Time for a different design. How is your COBOL or RPG? Do you know anything about the ILE?

I have no knowledge in that area.

The Integrated Language Environment; IBM i may not be for the faint of heart.

Some tables use collecting jobs written in COBOL. The data is written into an export file, where we query the data. I guess we have to do that for all tables. Thanks.

It looks like you can't use TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and CONCUR_UPDATABLE at the same time on AS/400. The documentation says:

There is one situation where the application specifies a TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, CONCUR_UPDATEABLE ResultSet. Insensitivity is implemented in the database engine by making a copy of the data. You are then not allowed to make updates through that copy to the underlying database. If you specify this combination, the driver changes the sensitivity to TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE and create the warning indicating that your request has been changed.


Thank you for your answer, but I thought that TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE ResultSets would only reflect updates on the selected data and would not see new records.

@Moh-Aw This type of cursor is sensitive to changes made to the database while it is open. Changes to the database have a direct impact on the ResultSet data.

Ok, that would mean there is no way I could fix this unless I change to a read only result set. I would have to find a different way to update the exported records.
